# How can I avoid getting a cartesian product in this join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to join two tables: one stores, for every date and hour, the available power from a collection of power generating equipment, and the other stores, for every date and hour, their variable cost:

**MDO_PROGDIA_POTDISPONIBLE:**

| DATE | HOUR | EQUIP | PROG_NUM | AV_POWER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 15se-g1 | -1 | 185.52 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u1 | -1 | 19.5 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u2 | -1 | 19.5 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u3 | -1 | 19.5 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u4 | -1 | 2.08696 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u5 | -1 | 0 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u6 | -1 | 40.07 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u7 | -1 | 40.07 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-g2 | -1 | 3.31683 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m1 | -1 | 2.72333 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m2 | -1 | 2.72333 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m3 | -1 | 0 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m4 | -1 | 2.72333 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m5 | -1 | 2.72333 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m6 | -1 | 2.72333 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-u1 | -1 | 24.71 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-u2 | -1 | 24.85 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-u4 | -1 | 27.94 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-u5 | -1 | 64.32 |

**MDO_PROGDIA_COSTOSVARIABLES:**

| DATE | HOUR | EQUIP | VAR_COST | PROG_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 15se-g1 | 92.270483 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u1 | 72.82923895 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u2 | 72.82923895 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u3 | 72.82923895 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u4 | 72.82923895 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u5 | 72.82923895 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u6 | 72.82923895 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | 5nov-u7 | 72.82923895 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-g2 | 125.85 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m1 | 132.88 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m2 | 132.88 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m3 | 132.88 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m4 | 132.88 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m5 | 132.88 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-m6 | 132.88 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-u1 | 214.17 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-u2 | 215.18 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-u4 | 364.33 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | acaj-u5 | 302.96 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | ahua-u1 | 4.819 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | ahua-u2 | 4.819 | -1 |
| 07/18/23 | 0 | ahua-u3 | 4.15 | -1 |

(PROG_NUM is a forecast number. In this example, that would be forecast -1)

My code results in a cartesian product. How can I get a single row for each unique combination of p.DATE, p.HOUR and p.EQUIP ?

```
select
    p.DATE,
    p.HOUR,
    p.EQUIP,
    p.AV_POWER,
    c.VAR_COST

FROM
    MDO_PROGDIA_POTDISPONIBLE p
    JOIN MDO_PROGDIA_COSTOSVARIABLES c ON
        p.DATE = c.DATE
        AND
        p.HOUR = c.HOUR
        AND
        p.EQUIP = c.EQUIP

WHERE
    p.DATE = to_date(:ddmmaa,'DDMMYY')

ORDER BY
    p.DATE,
    p.HOUR,
    c.VAR_COST,
    p.EQUIP
```

Comment: Your `MDO_PROGDIA_COSTOSVARIABLES.HOUR` column seems to contain only `0`...

Comment: Sample data is great, but a [mcve] also need you to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Your sample data is not correct. There are no matching rows between the two. Please correct your sample data to show realistic values so we can identify where you have a many-to-many join.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The `MDO_PROGDIA_COSTOSVARIABLES.HOUR` column contains only `0`s, because its the first hour of the day, immediately after midnight. For each hour of each day, there is one `VAR_COST` and also one `AV_POWER` for each `EQUIP`.
The result I would like is to match on `DATE`, `HOUR` and `EQUIP` and get the corresponding `AV_POWER` from one table and the `VAR_COST` from the other.

Comment: Your first table shows `acaj-g2` for all rows. The second table doesn't have this value at all. How do you expect to join the two and get any results?

Comment: Because they're large tables. `MDO_PROGDIA_POTDISPONIBLE` has 1,008 records. For every hour of the day, there is one record for each of 42 power generating equipments, likewise for `MDO_PROGDIA_COSTOSVARIABLES` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate (`group by`) your results

```
select
    p.DATE,
    p.HOUR,
    p.EQUIP,
    p.AV_POWER,
    SUM(c.VAR_COST) as VAR_COST

FROM
    MDO_PROGDIA_POTDISPONIBLE p
    JOIN MDO_PROGDIA_COSTOSVARIABLES c ON
        p.DATE = c.DATE
        AND
        p.HOUR = c.HOUR
        AND
        p.EQUIP = c.EQUIP

WHERE
    p.DATE = to_date(:ddmmaa,'DDMMYY')

GROUP BY
    p.DATE, p.HOUR, p.EQUIP, p.AV_POWER

ORDER BY
    p.DATE,
    p.HOUR,
    SUM(c.VAR_COST),
    p.EQUIP
```

This makes sure that for every combination of (DATE, HOUR, EQUIP, AV_POWER) you will have a single record maximum.